# Is there a possibility to generate OAuth-token with perl?

Tags: perl, oauth, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-authentication

I am currently developing an app that shall receive push notifications via Firebase.

Now the server, that should call he API on the trigger event is mainly written in Perl, so I try to write my own module that creates a HTTP request that calls the Firebase Server API.

For this request I have to generate an OAuth-Token as access token, which is kinda difficult to do in perl in my view, because I haven't found any module on CPAN that provides all the needed objects like `GoogleCredentials` in Java. Do you have any source for me, or a proper solution, you did by yourself?

Comment: Try https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OAuth

Comment: Just put "OAuth" into metacpan. There are a couple.

Comment: It is important to know if you are talking about OAuth 1 or OAuth 2 as they are very different (OAuth 2 is a lot simpler). If it's OAuth 1 I wrote [WWW::OAuth](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::OAuth) as a simpler/more reusable authenticator for this. But since you're talking about google I think it's OAuth 2.

Comment: Google is OAuth 2.0 only. Google dropped support for OAuth 1.x years ago.

Comment: I looked up for that on my own, it's in fact OAuth 2.0. Following the description on https://medium.com/@ThatJenPerson/authenticating-firebase-cloud-messaging-http-v1-api-requests-e9af3e0827b8 I downloaded my service account json but my server side script has to be written in perl and I didn't find an understandable example how to generate my OAuth token from that json.